# Flex mobile take multiple photo

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, flash-builder

I develop mobile application with flex 4.6 and ı need take photo and ı did it but some forms need multiple photo. How can ı take multiple photo on phone?
My codes are;

```
protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            if (CameraUI.isSupported){
                myCam = new CameraUI();
                myCam.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            }

        }
```

......

```
protected function button5_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            theImage.filters = [];
            theImage1.filters = [];
            theImage2.filters = [];
            theImage3.filters = [];
            if (CameraUI.isSupported){
                myCam.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);
            }
        }
        private function onComplete(evt:MediaEvent):void{
            theImage.source = evt.data.file.url;
            theImage1.source= evt.data.file.url;
            theImage2.source=evt.data.file.url;
            theImage3.source=evt.data.file.url;
        }
```

Comment: Do what you did to take one photo and execute that code again?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are storing the same data in multiple variables. If you need a dynamic number of photos, try adding it to an ArrayCollection like this:

```
private function onComplete(evt:MediaEvent):void{
    myPhotos.add(evt.data.file.url);
}
```

That way, for every photo taken, you simply add it to a list of all the photos you have so far.